# Conditional Formatting Formula for Multiple Conditions using Stop Light Icons in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a question about conditional formatting and using the stop light icons. I feel like this should be a common question but I couldn't find any easy solutions while searching.

Below is a column (column A) of percentages and the desired icon.

I want to use a formula to create stop light icons with multiple conditions. Anything equal to or greater than + or - 10% should be a red icon (any shape is fine at this point), anything greater than or equal to + or - 5% should be yellow, and anything between 0 and + or - 5 should be green.

I'm not too familiar with Excel formulas or VBA, so please provide a simple solutioin if possible.

A

30% - Red icon

6% - Yellow icon

2% - Green icon

-20% - Red icon

3% - Green icon

1% - Green icon

8% - Yellow icon

-9 - Yellow icon

Answer (score 0):

You will need a helper column.  Add an empty column next to your numbers.  Add this formula in the first cell:

```
=ABS(A1)
```

Then you can set your rules like this:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Then change the width of that column so it hides the numbers and shows the colors.

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works so I'll accept the answer. However I realized that I missed part of the question since I wrote it in a hurry. Based on your response, say for example that I wanted one cell to be an exception to the rule, cell 7B, which shows a yellow icon. What if I wanted this cell to be green, how do I manually change it or include a formula sepcifically for this cell that adjusts the icon colours?: